Can pedestrians and cyclists board shuttle trains in the Channel Tunnel?
Of course pedestrians can travel on the Eurostar trains through the Channel Tunnel (with limited options for transporting bicycles), but that's not what I mean. My question is: can pedestrians and/or cyclists board the shuttle trains between Coquelles, France and Folkestone, UK? If yes, how does it compare price-wise with the ferries? (For cars, a tunnel is significantly more expensive than a ferry.)
Oh, and I also don't mean cycling through the Tunnel like Chris Froome, even though I'd love to do that.

The price difference between the car through the tunnel and on a ferry are not fixed, in some cases the tunnel turns out to be cheaper, always worth to check both.

If we compare like for like, in my experience a ferry is a lot cheaper. Of course, a non-refundable tunnel ticket bought weeks in advance might be cheaper than a ferry ticket bought on the spot, but that's not a fair comparison.

In your experience, you have likely not travelled at the time my brother got a better deal on the channel two days out than on the ferry (for that same time of travel.) And I have heard more people about that. So it is worth to spend a few minutes to compare.

A long time ago there was Duo Line which were reciprocal bus services from Canterbury>Cité Europe in Calais and from Calais to Canterbury. They basically let you go to the other side for shopping as a foot passenger. I don't know if single tickets were allowed/tolerated. A few details on this page: http://www.photo-transport.co.uk/buses/cross-border/cross-border.htm. Obviously not an answer to this question btw!

Apparently so, if you travel by bike.

Taking your bike on LeShuttle is simple, with fares starting at just £50 per bicycle, each way. Our cycle service operates between the Holiday Inn Express in Folkestone and the CIFFCO building opposite Cite Europe in Calais, carrying cycles and cyclists on a specially adapted, spacious minibus. You'll be collected and taken to the terminal and onto the shuttle for the 35 minute journey.

A one-way ferry ticket for a bicycle costs £23.
Pedestrians are out of luck

Unfortunately, pedestrians cannot travel on the Eurotunnel Le Shuttle trains. They must use the Eurostar train or the ferries.

I think some buses go on the Shuttle, so that would be an option, depending on where exactly you are traveling. I'm not sure you can actually buy a ticket from Dover to Calais, but maybe I haven't searched hard enough.

How about pedestrians without bicycles?

Yeah, lots of buses use the Channel Tunnel, but I assume they don't make scheduled stops (for boarding and offboarding of passengers) on either side of the Channel. One would have to buy e.g. a Paris to London bus ticket

@Johnnyjanko Yes, I tried Flixbus which has stops in both Calais and Dover, but I can't seem to book a ticket to or from there.

Looking the link: Motorcycles travel at half the price of a car, so it seems it may be cheaper then bicycles.

@GiacomoCatenazzi It's counterintuitive, but I suppose the bicycle ticket includes a seat in the minibus, and the driver's wages

For pedestrians I believe I’ve seen stories about using a taxi for the ride, but that’s probably an expensive proposition, and it’s even possible it no longer works with Brexit.

@jcaron taking a beater bike with you would probably work out cheaper ;-)

@jcaron - it is possible to take a taxi even with Brexit - indeed I this is indeed the only currently available option if you are a pedestrian who wants to take their pet across the channel (e.g. https://lepetexpress.com/, https://petmovesabroad.co.uk/)

@NeilTarrant They aren't really taxis is the usual sense of the term, the first one at least is really a dedicated mini-bus service across the channel for pedestrians and their pets (which means they can arrange the necessary permits to work on both sides of the border, which a regular taxi may not be able to do, I'm not sure you can just hop on a taxi in Calais and tell the driver "to the UK, quick!"). £175 though. But they seem to sell the service like hot cakes! What wouldn't we do for our pets...

@Johnnyjanko I could find Calais-London or Lille-London so it's possible to take a bus not too far from the French end of the tunnel (and not only from Paris) but I couldn't find any bus with a stop in Kent.

Whilst the website suggests you can go by bike, this if often not the case. The "bike" option is actually a minibus that goes from a hotel. You cannot book it on the website, instead you have to contact them to make an enquiry.
This minibus service was out of action for a while and it is quite hard to get it booked. I have tried a few times and been told it isn't running.
tl;dr Don't assume you can cross, get in touch with them and see what the current status is.
I have used the ferry and £25 seems to be a standard price. I've booked on the app just hours before travel with no problem; capacity isn't an issue as there is plenty of space for cycles.
